# Recording video to MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, video, recording

I have an RCA feed with video. I'd like to capture this video to my Mac. I am looking for a mobile solution, something that does not require a wall plug, although battery power is OK. What methods exist to capture video on a laptop?

[Here is a solution](http://www.cooldrives.com/usb20miwire.html) (mini portable VCR) that does not use a computer, but if I can get it into my Mac for around that price, it would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Elgato Video Capture](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/products/Video-Capture/product1.en.html) takes video from a standard 3-plug RCA feed and records it to your Mac or PC in H.264 (they provide the recording software). It is USB-powered. $99 list, [$79 Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0029U2YSA).

Comment: Any idea how to handle having only a single RCA, not three?

Comment: Two plugs are for audio. Just leave those off, and I'm sure you'll get just video (the yellow one).